# Dynamically reference temp-table column values in Progress

Tags: progress-4gl

I am using Progress 4GL

I have a spreadsheet of data containing several columns called data1....50.

I have created a temp table which holds all the values.

Now I would like to loop through the temp table columns and do various calculations

So I need something like this:

```
for each record loop thru cols_in_temp_table .

   if col_value = "XYZ" then
     do calcs and stuff      

end.
```

So how do I reference the temp_table cols ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, this is one way to do it:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE h-cols  AS HANDLE   NO-UNDO.         

h-cols = tt-cols:BUFFER-HANDLE.                      

FOR EACH tt-cols                                     
   NO-LOCK:                                         

   IF h-cols::col-name = "some value" THEN       
       RUN do-something.                            

END.
```

For versions that can't do the "::" operator, do this:

```
FOR EACH tt-cols                                     
   NO-LOCK:                                         

   IF h-cols::buffer-field("col-name"):buffer-value = "some value" THEN       
       RUN do-something.                            

END.
```

Comment: DEFINE VARIABLE h-cols AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
h-cols  = BUFFER temptable:HANDLE.              

assign vi = 0.   
FOR EACH temptable NO-LOCK:

   assign vi = vi + 1.  
   IF h-cols:col-name <> "" THEN       
       message h-cols:name
           view-as alert-box info buttons ok.
           
   if vi > 2 then leave.
           

END. 

h-cols:col-name is not valid for 9.1e.  Have checked help documentation and there is no handle:colname or similar attribute, any ideas how i can get around this ?

Comment: Do this instead: 

h-cols:buffer-field("field-name"):buffer-value

Answer (score 0):

Ok, didn't resolve the original query, but found a workaround.  Split the data up and put into separate tables, long winded, but does the trick.